# Xamarin.Forms: How to set values in Style only on specific platform

Tags: xamarin.forms

In a style in xamarin forms (defined in xaml) I can define values platform specific, like this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Font" Android="30" iOS="40" WinPhone="20" x:Key="TitleFontSize" />

<Style x:Key="MyTitleLabel" TargetType="Label"">
    <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TitleFontSize}" />
</Style>
```

Can I also define the style in a way, so that the value of "Font" is kept to the default (not set at all) for some plarforms?

Something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTitleLabel" TargetType="Label"">
    <OnPlatform>
    <OnPlatform.Android>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="30" />
    </OnPlatform.Androud>
    </OnPlatform>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way avoid setting a value - if no value is specified it will default to `default(T)`.

But, with the latest XF version (> 2.4.0.282) there is a [`Default` property](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/OnPlatform.cs#L48) available that you can use to specify the fallback value.

```
<!-- specify default value here -->
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Default="25">
    <OnPlatform.Android>
        <Setter Property="Font" Value="30"/>
    </OnPlatform.Android>
</OnPlatform>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTitleLabel" TargetType="Label"">
   <Setter Property="Font">
     <Setter.Value>                   
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <On Platform="Android">30</On>
          <!--?<On Platform="iOS">20</On>-->
       </OnPlatform>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```